# React Redux <Provider> returning only store object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

The getState(), subscribe(), etc. methods of redux don't come into my  component, but only the initial store object comes in props of  component. What can I do with it to solve this issue?

### Props log

> store: {
>       pending: false,
>       fetchFailed: false,
>       authorized: false,
>       hash: '',
>       username: '', }

### App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Main from './views/Main';
import Auth from './views/Auth';

import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import initStore from './store/store';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: Main,
        path: 'Main',
    },
    Auth: {
        screen: Auth,
        path: 'Auth',
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    },
});

const AppNavigationContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

const config = {
    pending: false,
    fetchFailed: false,
    authorized: false,
    hash: '',
    username: '',
};

const store = initStore(config);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppNavigationContainer data={store} /> // Don't work data prop
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

### Store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from '../reducers/reducers';

const initStore = (preloadStore) => {
    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadStore, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
    return store;
};

export default initStore;
```

### Auth.js

```
// some code...
export default connect(
    (store) => ({
        store,
    }),
    (dispatch) => ({
        dispatch,
    }),
)(Auth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cannot pass props like that to the navigation container. You need to use `screenProps`.

However, in this case, it seems like you're doing something wrong. You're not supposed to access the `store` in the context. Instead, expose specific state items that you want to get: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: Work! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how `mapState` works.  The argument is not *the store instance*, the argument is *the store **state***.

Your own component shouldn't be accessing the actual store instance anyway.

Please see [the React-Redux docs page on using `mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) for instructions.